# What's the fastest horizontal travel possible in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

What is the fastest system to travel horizontally in Minecraft 1.16.5?

Comment: "Travel" suggests "for the player": is that what you mean? And what does "horizontal" mean: perpendicular to the ground, over the ground itself, whether it's flat or noisy, or through the air?

Comment: Yes, for the player. And horizontal means parallel to the ground. Doesn't have to be touching it or completely flat.

Comment: Thanks. And 'parallel', indeed - not perpendicular :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using hundreds of TNT to propel an ender pearl or a player wearing an elytra.

Here is a famous ender pearl cannon:

This is an older video and many newer designs have been created.

Here is a player cannon I saw: